# Convert (back and forth) UNIX timestamp to pandas.tslib.Timestamp and datetime for series

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, unix-timestamp

I am working with python 3.5.2, pandas 0.18.1 and sqlite3.

In my data base, I have a column `unix_time` with `INT` for seconds since 1970. Ideally I want to read my dataframe from sqlite, and then create a `time` column which would correspond to the `datetime` or `pandas.tslib.Timestamp` conversion of the `unix_time` column that I woul only use for some processing and then drop before saving the dataframe back.

The issue is that when **parsing** the `unix_time` column using :

```
df = pd.read_from_sql_query("SELECT * FROM test", con, parse_dates=['unix_time'])
```

I obtain `pandas.tslib.Timestamp` types which is fine for my processing, but then I have to recreate my original `unix_time` column using :

```
df['unix_time'][i] = (df['unix_time'][i] - datetime(1970,1,1)).total_seconds()
```

which is really 'dirty'

**First question** : Do you have a better way?

I thought about giving up the unix time format and only use `datetime` format but the `to_datetime` method from pandas returns in fact `pandas.tslib.Timestamp` ... And anyway, doing so would force me to iterate over all rows which is a bad solution. (It is impossible to apply `to_datetime` on something else than a view over a single cell of the dataframe

**Second question** : Is it possible to apply it on a series?

My last try was with directly using `df['time'] = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(df['unix_time'])` but surprisingly, it also returns `pandas.tslib.Timestamp`.

In the end, knowing that I can only save unix timestamps or datetimes, my only choices for the moment are :

- parsing but then having to convert them back to unix timestamp one by
  one.
- Or not parse it but have to convert them to `pandas.tslib.Timestamp`
  one by one.

It would be great if I could convert a whole series.

**Last question** : Is there a way to convert a unix timestamps series to `datetime` (or at least `pandas.tslib.Timestamp`), or a `pandas.tslib.Timestamp` (or `datetime`) series to unix timestamps?

Thanks

EDIT:
During my processing, I extract a row that I want to append to my dataset. Apparently, the coversion to `pandas.tslib.Timestamp` appends implicitly when passing from dataframe to serie :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'UNX':pd.date_range('2016-01-01', freq='9999S', periods=10).astype(np.int64)//10**9})
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.UNX, unit='s')
print(df.Date.dtypes)
print(type(df['Date'][0]))
test = df.iloc[0]
print(type(test.Date))
new_df = test.to_frame().transpose()   #from here, impossible to do : new_df.to_sql("test", con) because the type for 'Date' is not supported
print(new_df.Date.dtypes)
```

returns

```
datetime64[ns]
<class 'pandas.tslib.Timestamp'>
<class 'pandas.tslib.Timestamp'>
object
```

Is there a way to convert the 'Date' in `new_df` from `pandas.tslib.Timestamp` to `datetime64[ns]` or `datetime.datetime` (or simply `str`) ?

Comment: For series you can also use [`Series.dt.to_pydatetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.to_pydatetime.html) which replaced the deprecated `Series.to_datetime`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you can do it this way:

```
In [96]: df = pd.DataFrame({'UNX':pd.date_range('2016-01-01', freq='9999S', periods=10).astype(np.int64)//10**9})

In [97]: df
Out[97]:
          UNX
0  1451606400
1  1451616399
2  1451626398
3  1451636397
4  1451646396
5  1451656395
6  1451666394
7  1451676393
8  1451686392
9  1451696391
```

Convert UNIX epoch to Python datetime:

```
In [98]: df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.UNX, unit='s')

In [99]: df
Out[99]:
          UNX                Date
0  1451606400 2016-01-01 00:00:00
1  1451616399 2016-01-01 02:46:39
2  1451626398 2016-01-01 05:33:18
3  1451636397 2016-01-01 08:19:57
4  1451646396 2016-01-01 11:06:36
5  1451656395 2016-01-01 13:53:15
6  1451666394 2016-01-01 16:39:54
7  1451676393 2016-01-01 19:26:33
8  1451686392 2016-01-01 22:13:12
9  1451696391 2016-01-02 00:59:51
```

Convert `datetime` to UNIX epoch:

```
In [100]: df['UNX2'] = df.Date.astype('int64')//10**9

In [101]: df
Out[101]:
          UNX                Date        UNX2
0  1451606400 2016-01-01 00:00:00  1451606400
1  1451616399 2016-01-01 02:46:39  1451616399
2  1451626398 2016-01-01 05:33:18  1451626398
3  1451636397 2016-01-01 08:19:57  1451636397
4  1451646396 2016-01-01 11:06:36  1451646396
5  1451656395 2016-01-01 13:53:15  1451656395
6  1451666394 2016-01-01 16:39:54  1451666394
7  1451676393 2016-01-01 19:26:33  1451676393
8  1451686392 2016-01-01 22:13:12  1451686392
9  1451696391 2016-01-02 00:59:51  1451696391
```

Check:

```
In [102]: df.UNX.eq(df.UNX2).all()
Out[102]: True
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, it helped me see more precisely where I have issues. In fact, used this way everything works fine. I'll edit  my question to show where the types get messed up.

Answer (score 0):

Round trip between Pandas Timestamp and Unix Seconds (since 1970-01-01):

```
date_in = pd.to_datetime("2022-04-07")
# type(date_in) is: pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp
unix_seconds = date_in.value//10**9
date_out = pd.to_datetime(unix_seconds, unit="s")
```

Output:

```
date_in
Out[1]: Timestamp('2021-04-07 00:00:00')
unix_seconds
Out[2]: 1617753600
date_out
Out[3]: Timestamp('2021-04-07 00:00:00')
```